# Unit Testing In App purchase

Tags: android, unit-testing, in-app-purchase

I am writing an android application that involves inapp purchases. Do I have to write unit tests for codes involving fetching products from play store, making purchases etc. 
I believe we need a real device to test inapp purchases, in that case how will unit tests work?

Should I instead write instrumented test using expresso and check the inapp purchases are working as intended?

I am completely new to unit testing. Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several considerations.

- Yes you need an actual device for testing
- You probably don't want to make real purchases from an automated test, so that means logging in to the play store as a test user on the test device
- Considering that an in app purchase involves leaving your app to open a play store dialog, I would think an instrumented UI test would be the only way to do it.  Here's some documentation on testing multiple apps: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html
- Just a point of terminology, that would be an integration test since it's testing multiple systems working together